# Convert DLL to XSD

Tags: c#, xml, dll, xsd, xsd.exe

I create a simple class library which I want to transform in xsd. 
The content of the class library:

```
using System;

namespace XSDTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }
        }

        public Class1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When I rebuild app I have an assembly, and now I want to convert it to XSD using [XML Schema Definition Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen). I have the following problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in the path to the DLL.  Rename the directory to eliminate the space, or quote/escape the path so that the `xsd.exe` command sees it as a single argument, not two, space-separated arguments.

Comment: Ok, that helps. But now next error:

Error: There was an error processing 'C:\Temp\XSDtest\XSDTest.dll'.
  - Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

Comment: If that helped solve this problem, please accept/upvote this answer.  If you have a new problem, please ask a new question.  Thanks.